# Any instance of JVM using up 10's of Gigabytes of system memory

Tags: jvm

As soon as I open any application that uses the jvm, the jvm instance immediately uses up 5, 10, 20GB of memory until I force quit the jvm process or the system comes to a grinding pace. This is very frustrating. I've tried to re-install java, clear all caches. I'm not quite sure what to look for next.

I'm on OS X Mojave (this has been happening before I updated). This issue arises on any application that creates a jvm instance. IntelliJ, Clojure projects (using `lein`), even any Java debugging tools including the Java Control Panel. Literally everything that requires a JVM.

`$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)`

Comment: What is your OS, what the the JVM version, what applications did you start, does this also happen with a simple "Hello World" app?

Comment: edited main question to address this question.

Comment: What are your `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable? By default the JVM should use a few hundred MBS at worst, unless there is a setting to always start with more memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey How do I check this? `echo $JAVA_OPTS` returns a newline.

Comment: Can you try `set | grep JAVA` ?

Comment: `set | grep JAVA` returns `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home`